# Wmi сортировка выборки

Tags: windows

использую

```
 wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path win32_product where "name like '%%.NET%%'" get version
```

как можно сделать сортировку по версии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сортировку можно сделать несколькими способами:

- используя параметр `/format` ([ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858677/how-to-sort-wmic-process-according-to-the-memory-size?answertab=votes#tab-top) с англоязычного Stackoverflow, [справка по параметру](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757287%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), чуть больше [примеров](https://www.petri.com/command-line-wmi-part-3));
- средствами `Powershell` - командлет `Get-WMIObject` ([ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425958/sorting-wmic-output-with-in-commandline)  с англоязычного Stackoverflow).